# Swift - How to use user input in func with if-statement to decide output

Tags: swift, function, if-statement

I've been trying to write a function that takes user input and then returns the correct output in the textfield of my app, but can't get output.

What I have so far:

```
func outputResult (weeksNumber: Int, hoursNumber: Int) {

    let weeksNumber = Int(weeksNumber)
    let hoursNumber = Int(hoursNumber)

   let result1 = "test1" 
    let result2 = "test2"
    let result3 = "test3"

    if hoursNumber < 74 {
        resultText.text = result1 // ResultText being my textfield.
    } else if weeksNumber < 8 {
        resultText.text = result2
    } else {
        resultText.text = result3
    }
}
```

I've been trying to go through Apple's own material on functions and if-statements, but haven't been able to figure out how to do exactly what I want.

I've been trying out with:

```
func outputResult (weeksNumber: Int, hoursNumber: Int) - String {

    let weeksNumber = Int(weeksNumber)
    let hoursNumber = Int(hoursNumber)


    if hoursNumber < 74 {
        return resultText.text = "test1" 
    }
```

But this also doesn't solve my problem - merely giving me an error message.

My question is : How do I get my function to take user input and return output to my textfield?

Cheers,

Comment: Use the debugger to put a breakpoint in your function and step through it.  That will tell you if it's being called at all and, if so, how it's processing its input.  If you're getting an error message, paste it into your question so people have a chance of figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing "->" to specify that it has a return. And you have to have return on if else condition. Plus for this example you don't need new variables "weekNumber" and "hoursNumber" in function.

```
func outputResult (weeksNumber: Int, hoursNumber: Int) -> String {

        if hoursNumber < 74 {
            return resultText.text = "test1" 
        }else{
            return "default"
        }
 }
```

Comment: But specifying that return in the first function to be a string doesn't do the trick - But would have to be a different return, I can guess? (sorry, still new to Swift)

For my second example, wouldn't the function be useless if 'weekNumber' and 'hoursNumber' weren't there? How would the function check to see if the If-statement was fulfilled?

Comment: ouh, in the first function resultText is a textView?
You can try putting resultText.text = result inside  DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

})

So this would force it to update the screen.

Comment: resultText is a textView, yes. Apologies if that wasn't clear. I'll give your suggestion a try, thanks!

Comment: changing if statement to:
  if weeksNumber < 8 {
   return DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: resultText.text = result1) 
}

Returns the following error: "cannot invoke 'async' with an argument list of type '(execute: ())'..

Comment: Try This:

func outputResult (weeksNumber: Int, hoursNumber: Int) {
    
    let weeksNumber = Int(weeksNumber)
    let hoursNumber = Int(hoursNumber)

    var result = "test3"
    
    if hoursNumber < 74 {
        result = "test1"
    } else if weeksNumber < 8 {
        result = "test2"
    }
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
        resultText.text = result
    }
}

Comment: Unfortunately that function crashes my app in the simulator with the error:
"libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException".

I'm wondering if there's a different or even easier way to get to where I'd like to be.

Comment: Interesting, that could be something else. it's hard to tell without seeing the project.

Comment: I don't know where to present/show the project as it stands currently, but any help would be appreciated. 

I'm guessing the error must be connected to the function in question since that's the only thing changed from when the app worked to the error message :)

But even if I don't find a solution to my problem, then you've been a massive help already!